# Getting the declaring class of an instance: possible?

Tags: java, class, reflection, instance

Is there any way to retrieve the declaring class of an instance at runtime?
For example:

```
public class Caller {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    private JButton button = new JButton("Test me");
    private Callee callee = new Callee();

    public Caller() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        button.addActionListener(callee.getListener());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Caller();
    }
}
```

The callee:

```
public class Callee {
    public ActionListener getListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /* Get the class "Caller" here and invoke its methods */
                /* Something along the lines of: */
                Object button = e.getSource();
                button.getOwnerClass(); //This would return the type Caller
            }
        };
    }
}
```

"getOwnerClass()" is an imaginary method. Is there a way to get a result similar to that?

Comment: A reference to the "Callee" can be stored at multiple locations, the "Caller" is nothing special => Anwser is no.

Comment: Do you mean `Caller.class`?

Comment: What would that give you? What could you do consistently with that information? You could get it with the stack trace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Assume the Callee's ActionListener is used by multiple classes, all of which share a method (implemented by an interface).

Comment: You can't make that assumption for all of Java though. So something so specific cannot exist. You can access the stack trace and get types on the stack, but you never know how far down the stack to go.

Comment: Implement the observer/callback pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the standard API that allows you to get this information. It's a bit unclear what you mean with 'declaring class' or 'owner class' but for this sake of this answer I'll assume that it is the class whose code created the instance of the object (that you want the owner class from).

This information is not stored by the JVM by default.

But, using [the heap profiler that is packaged along with the JDK distribution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html), you can record the stacktrace of the point at which objects are allocated, and this information can be written to a file on various points in time.

That still doesn't give you an API call to retrieve the information, but it shows that it is technically possible to record this type of information.

I search a bit on Google and found that someone did create an API that uses the same basic technique as the heap profiler (the `java.lang.instrumentation` package/JVMTI interface)

- Open source project: [java-allocation-instrumenter](https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/)

With a bit of work you should be able to build something with it.

The site has a nice example:

```
AllocationRecorder.addSampler(new Sampler() {
    public void sampleAllocation(int count, String desc, Object newObj, long size) {
      System.out.println("I just allocated the object " + newObj + 
        " of type " + desc + " whose size is " + size);
      if (count != -1) { System.out.println("It's an array of size " + count); }
    }
});
```

Instead of printing, you should get the stacktrace using `new Exception().getStackTrace()`, remove the first few `StackTraceElement` objects that refer to the sampler and the API classes, and then call `StackTraceElement.getClassName()` to get the name of the class that created the object instance, in other words, your OwnerClass.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion; your assumption is correct. However, while the Allocation Instrumenter project is definitely interesting, it isn't exactly what I was looking for - it would make the code too complicated (and dependent) for something I had hoped to be fairly simple.